# Facebook feed dialog redirect uri_problem

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-opengraph

I am developing an app which provides a facebook feed dialog. I am using the following code:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
  app_id=123050457758183&
  link=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&
  picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&
  name=Facebook%20Dialogs&
  caption=Reference%20Documentation&
  description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&
  message=Facebook%20Dialogs%20are%20so%20easy!&
  redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response
```

Now, in the redirect_uri part i want to redirect the user back again to my app. I am providing address here as http://apps.facebook.com/myapp but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know its the best practice available or so to overcome the problem...

But I use the canvas url in redirect_uri pointing thank to thank page

```
http://www.xyz.com/fbapp/thankyou.php
```

and after user click button, redirect_uri page loads where my server scripts is already waiting for some special parameter for e.g.

```
?thank=1
```

based on the parameter perform another redirect to app page.

Added: use https instead of http in each of your parameters url